# confusion on meaning of equilibrium state of a system

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I have some confusions on the idea of equilibrium state of a system.So I will write down what I think about equilibrium state and what is the confusion I have.

Equilibrium state is the stable state of the system(like a minima of a potential)

At the equilibrium condition the entropy will attain its maximum value.
The maximum value of the entropy means the disorderedness of the system is at maximum.

I think(or believe) that both disorderedness and stability are kind of two opposite words(means stability imply order and vice versa),so by this way for me its confusing what its actually mean by equilibrium state?

Comment: If a system is in a maximum entropy state, say a bucket of water at a given temperature everywhere within it,  is that not a stable, but still as disordered as possible,  state? Apologies if I misunderstand you, but  please bear with me, I don't know much about thermodynamics. If it is not at maximum entropy, is it not still unstable, as it can still "move" to a maximum entropy state?

Comment: Disorderedness and stability are not opposites. If you see something highly ordered (say, a neatly organized silverware drawer, or a box in which all the gas molecules within it are confined to a small location) you should expect it to change. Disorder is stable, because there's nowhere for the system to go to get "more disordered."

Comment: what I mean by stability is ,suppose the system is not at equilibrium,and leaving the system like that,so as the time evolve the system will tend to equilibrium state(like a particle away from minima tend to minimum potential state(stable state)).

Comment: @azad right, that's what we mean too. An ordered state will change to a disordered state if you let it time evolve. A disordered state will not time evolve.

Comment: no,but probably for non equilibrium state they might have used taylor series(not sure)>

Answer (score 1):

Equilibrium state of the system essentially means that you can define **all** the macroscopic state variables uniquely i.e. one can assign unique values(for **A ,U,S etc)** for the whole system and it remains a constant in time i.e it is stable.

stability and dis-orderness are not opposite, in fact, the description of entropy as disorder is quite confusing. Better  to express the entropy as the amount of knowledge (information) about the system. In an equilibrium state, we will have  maximum information of the system.

while if the system is not at equilibrium, then it essentially implies that it is undergoing irreversible change for which we cannot define state variables uniquely and hence we will have *less* information about the system.

maximum information implies no change in entropy whereas any lack of information implies  entropy increases.